# TFS 2008 very slow - what to do about it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We have a small TFS setup (only 3 -4 developers use it), but it has been in use since 2008 and is lately getting excruciatingly slow to respond, for checkout, work item reports, you name it. VS2008 sometimes slows down to a grinding halt (frozen for several minutes) when changing compile mode, for example.
Clearing the client cache has made no difference, and the server does not appear to have a similar cache folder (not that I can find). However I notice that the TFSBuild database has some very large tables (TestResult, for example). I am sure we don't need this information for ourselves because we never go back to previous test results more than a day or so.

My question is: is there a good guide to managing all this data, to keep TFS working smoothly? Is there a set of tools that will enable me to clear out unwanted data and so on? We are getting to the stage where it is costing us a great deal of time just waiting for things to happen, which was never the case a few years ago.

Clients: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008 TFS.

Server: Windows 2003 R2. TFS 2008 & Sql Server 2005.

I should add that we are not interested in retaining information on more than the last few builds, although I notice that the database seems to be retaining data on huge amounts of previous builds, going back to 2009. No use to us at all. Can this all safely be deleted somehow?

Comment: Have you run Best Practices Analyser?

Comment: Our office had issues like this for years. We ended up switching to SVN.

Comment: Best Practices Analyser? What's that?

Comment: Ok, got it. Will see what that reveals.

Comment: Well BPA tells me it cannot tell me anything useful, because the domain administrator account I used to run it is not a Team Foundation Administrator, but Visual Studio Team explorer tells me it most definitely is a member of the Team Administrators group! Hopelesss. So that's not getting me anywhere. I need some tools to clear out the unnecessary data from TFS. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you need to stick with VS2008? If you can upgrade to either VS2010 or VS2012, then you could switch to a TFS2012 server, which is significantly better than TFS2008 - for a team of up to 5 users there is an Express version of TFS which is free. (VS2010/2012 are also both much faster than 2008 when working with large numbers of projects in a solution)

Answer (score 0):

I would bet on the database side.

Did you check the database transaction log?
Check that the database backup are correctly configured. I have seen HUGE transaction logs way too many times on TFS installations.

Did you check the retention policies on your build definitions ?

If you have been using the testing features a lot, you might want to run the Test Attachement Cleaner to remove the old attachment from the test results.

You can also have a look at outdated workspaces, especially the ones with pending changes.

This [MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2013/10/08/what-does-a-well-maintained-team-foundation-server-look-like.aspx) and [this one](http://osnabrugge.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/top-10-of-things-every-tfs-administrator-should-do/) could also give you pointers.